Adjust the number and text to be the same size when using enumerate
I want to make both numbers and letters big and bold so I use \LARGE \textbf{\arabic*} with enumerate but fail.
My current code:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\LARGE \textbf{\arabic*}]
\item  XYZ MLK (1830 - 1900)
ABC

\item KKK LLL (1920 - 1960) 
hlk myu
\end{enumerate}


Please adjust the text and number to be the same size. Thanks

Please try to make your question clear and simple by providing a minimal working example.

There's no way that your input can produce the shown picture.

You can put everything inside a large and bold scope:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

{\LARGE \bfseries
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*}]
\item  XYZ MLK (1830 - 1900)
ABC

\item KKK LLL (1920 - 1960) 
hlk myu
\end{enumerate}
}

\end{document}


